# Reducing the aerodynamic drag of multi-engined rockets: aft wake area

Tags: rockets, atmospheric-drag, aerodynamics

Have there ever been thoughts of reducing the aerodynamic drag that results from the empty space between rocket engines? More precisely, this extremely low-pressure area sucks up ambient air and accelerates it in the direction of the rockets motion. So actually I have two questions:

1. is this drag significant compared to the shockwave drag in the front, frictional drag, and gravitational drag?
2. if so, are there any concepts of reducing this kind of drag?

I'm thinking about something like air injection, e.g. either passive by means of [NACA ducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_duct), or active. Or maybe some sort of coverage of this void area. But then again I am not sure how much airflow is needed around the nozzles for cooling.

Comment: It can be significant based on the configuration.  Errors in preflight compuations of the base drag on the Shuttle mated vehicle contributed to a 10,000 ft error in SRB separation altitude (predicted vs. actual). See page 184 in http://klabs.org/DEI/Processor/shuttle/shuttle_tech_conf/1985008580.pdf